# Filling a view dynamically?

Tags: java, android, view

I'm trying to create a sort of product viewer. I've got the list with products working but I need it to open a separate product view if I click on one of the items in that list. I've tried passing the Id of a product to the new activity but for some reason it won't work. Can anybody help? Thanks in advance.

This is my product list:

```
public class inside_category extends Activity {

private static String _category;
List<product> Products = new ArrayList<product>();
ListView productListView;
private static List<product> productCategory = new ArrayList<product>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inside_category);
    setTitle(_category);
    productListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    addProduct();
    populateList();

    productListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            product_view productviewer = new product_view();
            productviewer.setCurrentProductId(productCategory.get(position).getId());
            productviewer.setTitle(productCategory.get(position).getProductName());
            Intent intent = new Intent(inside_category.this, product_view.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.inside_category, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public static List<product> getProductCategory(){
    return productCategory;
}

public static void setCategory(String category){
    _category = category;
}

public void addProduct(){
    Products.add(new product("Socket AM3+",1, "i7", "Dayum", 430));
    Products.add(new product("Socket AM3+",2, "Cool", "yeah", 430));
    Products.add(new product("Socket 2011",3, "i5", "Not that dayum", 200));
    Products.add(new product("AMD",4, "i7", "Dayum", 430));
    Products.add(new product("Nvidia",5, "i5", "Not that dayum", 200));
    Products.add(new product("DDR2",6, "i7", "Dayum", 430));
    Products.add(new product("ATX",7, "i5", "Not that dayum", 200));

    int listLength = Products.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < listLength; i++){
        if(Products.get(i).getListId().contains(_category)){
            productCategory.add(Products.get(i));
        }
    }
}

private void populateList(){
    ArrayAdapter<product> adapter = new ProductListAdapter();
    productListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}


public String getCategory(){
    return _category;
}

private class ProductListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<product>{
    public ProductListAdapter(){
        super (inside_category.this, R.layout.product, productCategory);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (view == null)
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.product, parent, false);

        product prod = productCategory.get(position);

        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.productTitle);
        name.setText(prod.getProductName());
        TextView price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.productPrice);
        price.setText("€"+prod.getProductPrice());

     return view;
    }
}
}
```

This is the class I'm trying to pass the product to:

```
public class product_view extends Activity {
int currentProductId;
String Name, Description, ListId;
int Price;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_view);
    populate();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.product_view, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void setCurrentProductId(int currentProductId){
    this.currentProductId = currentProductId;
}

public int getCurrentProductId(){
    return currentProductId;
}

private void populate(){
    for(int i = 0; i > prodCat.size(); i++ ){

        if(prodCat.get(i).getId() == currentProductId){
            Name = prodCat.get(i).getProductName();
            Price = prodCat.get(i).getProductPrice();
            Description = prodCat.get(i).getProductDescription();
            ListId = prodCat.get(i).getListId();
        }
    }

    product currentProduct = new product(ListId, currentProductId, Name, Description, Price);

    TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.productNameTitle);
    name.setText(currentproduct.getProductName());
    TextView price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.productPriceView);
    price.setText("€"+currentproduct.getProductPrice());
    TextView productType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.productTypeId);
    productType.setText(currentproduct.getListId());
    TextView description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.productDescriptionView);
    description.setText(currentproduct.getProductDescription());
}
 }
```

Comment: if you wan pass product whole info then you have make your product class Serializable with implements of Serializable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot instantiate product_view Activity like this.

```
 product_view view = new product_view();
```

and then call its methods,

You will have to pass the product id, or the entire product object as an Intent extra to your product_view class like this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(inside_category.this, product_view.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_ID", productCategory.get(position).getId());
startActivity(intent);
```

And then in your product_view Activity do the below to get the ID.

```
String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_ID");
```

Using this id, you can fetch your product and populate in product_view Activity accordingly.

In case you cannot get the data only using the ID, you can also pass the entire product object via the Intent. See [this for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android).

Comment: I've tried using the SerializableExtra but it gives a nullpointerexception.. It seems like the object I'm passing is empty?

Comment: What are you passing and how are you passing? Can you update your code with the new one?

Comment: I've got it working now, thanks anyway. The only thing that still doesn't work is the if statement in populate() in product_view is never true and I can't figure out why...

Comment: If I helped you in any way, you can upvote and accept my answer. :) And if you are passing intents then set the currentProductId with the ID your are passing via the Intent.

Comment: No issues :) Glad I was able to help. Did the if issue solve?

Comment: What is inside_category? Can you check its size, if it contains data or not?

Comment: I changed it so that prodCat is filled by a list passed by the intent, i've checked that prodCat's size is 2 so I know it's filled. (I also checked if they had values in them, which they did. but the for loop with if statement is not filling Name and the other variables

Comment: Thats great Mark. :) Have fun coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `ProductListAdapter` needs to override the `getItemId` method:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position){
   // return the id(), or whatever you use to access the id on your product object
   return productCategory.get(position).id();
}
```